# SpringFramework ResponseBody returns objects with null values

Tags: java, json, spring, serialization

I have a RestController that sends back a list of Film objects to the user:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/view")
public class FilmRestController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET,  produces = "application/json")
    public @ResponseBody List<Film> getCurrentFilms(){
        FilmInfo filmInfo = new FilmInfo();
        return filmInfo.getCurrentFilms();
    }
}
```

Each Film object contains two Strings (title, director) and List which are the actors. So fairly simple pojo.

when I do the request in Postman I get the following response:

```
[
{
    "title": null,
    "director": null,
    "actors": null
},
{
    "title": null,
    "director": null,
    "actors": null
},
{
    "title": null,
    "director": null,
    "actors": null
},
{
    "title": null,
    "director": null,
    "actors": null
}
]
```

I thought this was a glitch at first so I wrote the following method after:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getOneFilm", method = RequestMethod.GET,  produces = "application/json")
public @ResponseBody Film getOneFilm(){
    Film film = new Film("The Shawshank Redemption", "Frank Darabont", Arrays.asList("Tim Robbins","Morgan Freeman","Bob Gunton"));
    return film;
}
```

And sure enough my Response was:

```
{
"title": null,
"director": null,
"actors": null
}
```

As requested here is my Film class:

```
package entities;

import java.util.List;

public class Film {

private String title;
private String director;
private List<String> actors;

public Film(String title, String director, List<String> actors) {
    title = this.title;
    director = this.director;
    actors = this.actors;
}


public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}
public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}
public String getDirector() {
    return director;
}
public void setDirector(String director) {
    this.director = director;
}
public List<String> getActors() {
    return actors;
}
public void setActors(List<String> actors) {
    this.actors = actors;
}
}
```

Is there a reason ResponseBody cannot convert my object to be sent back in the Response? Should I change tactics and manually do my JSON serializer? I

Comment: Can you post your class `Film` ? And when you use annotation `RestController`, you don't need `ResponseBody` annotations. `public Film getOneFilm(){` should work perfectly.

Comment: @CrazySabbath I have added my Film class to the question. I would had thought it works perfectly too. But unfortunately it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your constructor you are updating the parameter instead of the attributes:

```
public Film(String title, String director, List<String> actors) {
    title = this.title;
    director = this.director;
    actors = this.actors;
}
```

The attributes in your class stay null. Change it to:

```
public Film(String title, String director, List<String> actors) {
    this.title = title;
    this.director = director;
    this.actors = actors;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I never have gotten them mixed up before. My eyes do that sometimes though :<